# Insert query syntax error when run using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data using the following query

```
INSERT INTO events(
    '_id', 
    'id', 
    '_kafka.topic', 
    '_kafka.partition', 
    '_kafka.offset', 
    '_kafka.timestamp', 
    '_kafka.key', 
    '_kafka.simulated', 
    '_kafka.consumed'
)
VALUES(
    "{'$oid': '5daa639e4176a8d0301beb0c'}", 
    '0', 
    'Events_227_v3', 
    '2', 
    '22938980', 
    "{'$date': '2019-10-19T01:15:10.355Z'}", 
    "b'0'", 
    'False', 
    "{'$date': '2019-10-19T01:15:10.913Z'}"
)
```

Error message

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''_id', 'id', '_kafka.topic', '_kafka.partition', '_kafka.offset', '_kafka.timest' at line 1

What is causing this error?

Comment: there won't be any quotes for column names `''`. Instead use back ticks `\``

Comment: INSERT INTO events(_id, id, _kafka.topic, _kafka.partition, _kafka.offset, _kafka.timestamp, _kafka.key, _kafka.simulated, _kafka.consumed) VALUES("{'$oid': '5daa639e4176a8d0301beb0c'}", '0', 'Events_227_v3', '2', '22938980', "{'$date': '2019-10-19T01:15:10.355Z'}", "b'0'", 'False', "{'$date': '2019-10-19T01:15:10.913Z'}")

when I used this I get 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '_kafka.topic' in 'field list'

Comment: If you got your answer make as "Accepted" use the tick button on left side of answer

Answer (score 1):

On `Insert` the column name shouldn't enclosed using single `'` or double quotes `"`.

Instead mention just the column name or use back ticks (`).

Suppose you have table like `events` and `_kafka`

And when executing the below `Insert` query

`INSERT INTO events(id, _kafka.topic) VALUES( '1', 'Events_227_v3')`

It will throw an error `Unknown column '_kafka.topic' in 'field list'`

since the column `topic` doesn't exists in the table `events`.

Comment: column existed...I figured a way through. Thanks for helping

Comment: Yes you should use back ticks which i have mentioned in comment as well as in answer

Answer (score 0):

The column names have a dot used in them.

Thus they required to be in following manner

```
INSERT INTO events(`_id`, `id`, `_kafka.topic`, `_kafka.partition`, `_kafka.offset`, `_kafka.timestamp`, `_kafka.key`, `_kafka.simulated`, `_kafka.consumed`) VALUES("{'$oid': '5daa639e4176a8d0301beb0c'}", '0', 'Events_227_v3', '2', '22938980', "{'$date': '2019-10-19T01:15:10.355Z'}", "b'0'", 'False', "{'$date': '2019-10-19T01:15:10.913Z'}")
```

Usage of ` symbol was required alongwith the column names.

For example, if column name is col.name then in the query it should be like `col.name`